# Hibernate: Risks associated with changing DiscriminatorValue

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

Given:

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="postType", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Post {}

@DiscriminatorValue(value = PostType.BUG)
public class BugReport extends Post {}
```

That is ... Bugs start life in this system as a Post.  Later, they can be promoted(?) to being a BugReport.

I'm using the following approach to update this:

```
@Transactional
public Post setPostType(Post post, String postType)
{
    SQLQuery sql = getSession().createSQLQuery("UPDATE post SET postType = :postType where id = :id");
    sql.setString("postType", postType);
    sql.setInteger("id", post.getId());
    sql.executeUpdate();

    getSession().evict(post);
    getSession().flush();

    Post newPost = get(post.getId());
    return newPost;
}
```

Although this works,  (the post type is changed, and returned from the db as a `BugReport`).  I'm curious if there are any side effects or risks associated with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Although this works, (the post type is changed, and returned from the db as a BugReport). I'm curious if there are any side effects or risks associated with this approach.

One problem I can see is that you are bypassing optimistic locking checks and a concurrent transaction updating the same `Post` could thus override the changes. So you should probably include the version check in your update and throw an exception if the count returned by `executeUpdate` is not `1`.